# SVN global and local version

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am wanting to setup an SVN that will contain 7 directories for seven different interfaces within the trunk folder.

Sometimes I have to make changes to one of these interfaces however when I do so the revision numbers for all folders increments.

How can I setup the SVN so that if a change is made in one of the directories in trunk , it does not affect others?

Or is this not possible?

e.g.

trunk (rev 1)

- interface a (rev 1)
- interface b (rev 1)
- interface c (rev 1)

I make a change to interface b it then becomes

trunk (rev 2)

- interface a (rev 1)
- interface b (rev 2)
- interface c (rev 1)

So that when designers / devs look they can see in the newest iteration of the sytem has only one interface that has been changed. So they can ignore the others and just deploy the change tothe live environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I setup the SVN so that if a change is made in one of the directories in trunk , it does not affect others?

Do nothing, just understand and use Subversion in the right way:

Revision of each node in SVN-tree is the latest revision of *all node's childs*, i.e, in your case, after commit to `interface b` (as revision 2) directory /trunk will have rev 2, interface b - rev 2 also, but last-change-revision of `interface a`|`interface c` is still rev 1 (they haven't childs in rev 2)

Use `svn ls -v URL/TO/DIR` in order to see it.

Sample for branches subtree in my repository

Branches node

```
>svn ls -v http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/
     37 lazybadg              янв 19  2013 ./
     37 lazybadg              янв 19  2013 branches/
     22 lazybadg              июл 17  2010 tags/
     36 lazybadg              янв 09  2013 trunk/
```

First column of output is revision (latest changes in) of *this node* - for `/branches` tree it's 37

Real branches

```
>svn ls -v http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/
     37 lazybadg              янв 19  2013 ./
     28 lazybadg              фев 22  2011 Leichtbau-Deutsch/
     37 lazybadg              янв 19  2013 branche-francaise/
     25 lazybadg              сен 14  2010 i18n/
```

Branches have revision 37, because `branche-francaise` subdir was changed last time in 37, but others subdirs have own (older) revision of change, which you can get and test and compare.

Same rule applied to any part of repository-tree, to your trunk - also

**Final note**: it is Bad Idea (tm) to use Devs or Designers for deploy, remember "MYOB" rule. Deploy can (and have to) be automated in order to decrease delays and human-errors (post-commit hook may be good candidate for this type of job)